# Addition in C++

Tags: c++, function, addition, arithmetic-expressions

I'm beginning to write a calculator program in C++ and I'm not able to get the addition to work right. I've tried different types of numbers, using strings and then casting to an int, encapsuling the function in a class, all with no avail. Help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to C++ (Java is my main language). Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int calcIt(int a, char b, int c){
    int result = 0;
        if(b == '+'){
            result =(a+b);
        }
    return result;
}
int main(){
    int aa;
    char bb;
    int cc;
    cout << "Int a: " << endl;
    cin >> aa;
    cout << "Operand: " << endl;
    cin >> bb;
    cout << "Int b: " << endl;
    cin >> cc;
    cout << "That is: " << calcIt(aa,bb,cc) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input and the resulting output?

Comment: `if(b== '+'){ result =(a+b); }` that is supposed to be `a+c`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int calcIt(int a, char b, int c){
    int result = 0;
    if (b == '+'){
        result = (a + c);  // <<------ this was a + b
    }
    return result;
}
int main(){
    int aa;
    char bb;
    int cc;
    cout << "Int a: " << endl;
    cin >> aa;
    cout << "Operand: " << endl;
    cin >> bb;
    cout << "Int b: " << endl;
    cin >> cc;
    cout << "That is: " << calcIt(aa, bb, cc) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot believe that I did that! I've been working on this code for 2 days with that bug!

Comment: @AustinDuffie: Have someone show you how to step through with a debugger, that will teach you how to find and solve these sorts of issues in any language.

Comment: Thanks, I know I should use a debugger. I'll get on to googling how to use GDB.